# Poetry Update Failed

Tags: windows, python-poetry

I installed [OOO Development Tools](https://github.com/Amourspirit/python_ooo_dev_tool) following the [Windows install](https://python-ooo-dev-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev_docs/dev_notes.html#windows) which created a venv then runs `poetry install`.

The package was updated so I ran `poetry update` but it returned:

> No dependencies to install or update

`poetry show` does not show the `ooo-dev-tools` package. Using `pip show ooo-dev-tools` I can see an old package version is installed in the venv.

How can the package be updated to the latest release?

Comment: I understand I need to update the local repository then run `poetry install`

Answer (score 1):

`poetry update` updates the dependencies of the package `ooo-dev-tools` i.e, the dependencies mentioned in its `pyproject.toml` file to its latest version; bound to the version limits set in the toml file.

But I believe you want to actually update the root package `ooo-dev-tools` itself for this you would have to pull the latest changes to the cloned repo `ooo-dev-tools` and then do the `poetry update` and `poetry install`. (would be smooth as long as there are no big updates like change in python version or so...)

On the other hand, if you had the `ooo-dev-tools` installed as a dependency of another project and it is mentioned under `[tool.poetry.dependencies]`  of the `pyproject.toml` then the `poetry update` will be considering this package as well for updation to latest version.

Comment: Yes, I'm really trying to understand how to update `ooo-dev-tools` _and_ it's dependencies. Can you focus a little more on that? There is no other project but it sounds like that might be the easiest way.

Comment: for updating the project you can go to the root folder of `ooo-dev-tools` and just do a `git fetch` which shows you the changes in the origin and then do `git merge` to update your local files to the latest ones. Then follow the steps in the answer above with poetry to install this updated project.

Comment: That is very much part of one option in your answer but a git process _and_ poetry defeat the concept of package management. I'm more interested in extending poetry package management to the main repo.